# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem -- is new WaitCallback() required?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

90% of examples I see, including MSDN use this syntax:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyCallback));
```

the other 10% use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyCallback);
```

Where MyCallback is a static function, in both cases.

The compiler doesn't give an error and the code appears to work either way.  Is there some danger with not creating a new WaitCallback object and just passing the function directly?

I ask because I'm trying to locate some bugs in my code, which I'll address with more specific questions once I narrow it down, but also this general question because I've always been curious and couldn't find any answers.  The closest I found was this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Which states:

> "Visual Basic users can omit the WaitCallback constructor, and simply
>   use the AddressOf operator when passing the callback method to
>   QueueUserWorkItem. Visual Basic automatically calls the correct
>   delegate constructor."

...but doesn't actually say "C# users MUST use the constructor", and I'd also like to know **why**/details.  I'm using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyCallback));
```

and

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyCallback);
```

are equivalent and are compiled to the same byte code. The compiler inserts the `new WaitCallback` call for you.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx):

> ```
> Del<int> m1 = new Del<int>(Notify);
> ```
>
> C# version 2.0 has a new feature called method group conversion, which applies to concrete as well as generic delegate types, and enables you to write the previous line with this simplified syntax:
>
> ```
> Del<int> m2 = Notify;
> ```